# Windows Phone 8.1 WinJS AppBar disappears if I leave the app (suspended) and go back inside

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

Everything works perfectly. The appbar is displayed only in the home, but if I exit the App without closing and again opening it, it disappears the appbar

In **home.js**

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
    appBar = document.getElementById("createAppBar").winControl;
        appBar.getCommandById("cmdSettings").addEventListener("click", doClickSettings, false);
        appBar.getCommandById("cmdCalibrate").addEventListener("click", doClickCalibrate, false);
        appBar.getCommandById("cmdShare").addEventListener("click", doClickShare, false);
        appBar.getCommandById("cmdEdit").addEventListener("click", doClickCamera, false);
        getLoc();

    }});
...
```

In **home.html**

```
<div id="createAppBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{closedDisplayMode:'minimal'}">
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdSettings',label:'Ajustes',icon:'settings',tooltip:'Ajustes'}"></button>
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdCalibrate',label:'Calibrar',icon:'fourbars',tooltip:'Calibrar'}"></button>
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdShare',label:'Compartir',icon:'like',tooltip:'Corre la voz'}"></button>
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdEdit',label:'about',icon:'like',tooltip:'Corre la voz'}"></button>
<!--<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdCamera',label:'Camera',icon:'camera',section:'selection',tooltip:'Take a picture'}"></button>-->
```

Can someone help me?
Tnx in adv!

Comment: Are you hiding/removeing you ApplicationBar somewhere (Suspending/OnNavigatedFrom etc.)?

Comment: No, I only want it to appear on the page "home", no I want to display it on the page "Settings". Therefore, I have the "createAppBar" div only in "home".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug in WinJS.

https://github.com/winjs/winjs/issues/140